# Unix sed command works on terminal but not write changes to file output

Tags: sed

I'm facing the following problem:
Whenever I try to redirect to an output file the following command, the changes does not get reflected in the output file:

```
sed '/^20/{N;/\n20/!{s/\n//};P;D}' line_test.csv > file.tmp
```

But if I run only the command without the output redirection, the expected result is shown on the terminal and don't change the file (but I want the file to get changed):

```
sed '/^20/{N;/\n20/!{s/\n//};P;D}' line_test.csv
```

Anyone has an idea?
thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error while running re-direction command?

Comment: What's in `file.tmp` then? The unchanged input file?

Comment: I m not sure, but change the name of output file

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I'm not getting any error. Simply the file.tmp gets exactly the same content as line_test.csv

Comment: @BenjaminW., exactly.

Comment: @RaviSaroch, already did that. Also tried a couple of other things, like adding -i, or using the mv to other file etc.

Comment: Can you show the minimal actual contents of `line_test.csv` for which you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @BenjaminW., the content is a couple of lines like '2009/CPC;1234;9887;xxxx'.

Comment: So, for an input file with exactly two lines like that, the problem occurs?

Comment: Yes, no matter how many line the file have. When I have a line that matches with the command, simply does not do that to the output file

Comment: Is the difference that the one with no redirection is run interactively and the one that does have redirection is run from inside a shell script (not interactively)?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, I don't know if I understand you correctly, but both scripts were run directly in the shell. Neither one are inside a shell script.